# How do I use different wallpaper on each workspace?

Tags: 10.04, gnome, compiz, desktop-background

I want to use different wallpaper on each workspace, but the    following does not change background wallpapers:

> > There are problem ....left -right at click on    workspaces.(Ubuntu 10.04)...
> >
> > startwall.sh a file I have created  and I called Terminal in sh startwall.sh and I added Startup Application and I have Run to applicatiion.But I want to Play as   Automatic Background always on each Workshapes.
>
> ```
>            Code:
> ```

```
#!/bin/bash     
ws=$(wmctrl -d | wc -l)
cws=$(wmctrl -d | awk '/*/    {print $1}')   
lws=$(($cws-1))
if [ $lws = -1 ]; then
    lws=$(($ws-1)) 

    gconftool -t string -s /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename "/root/Desktop/wall/b.jpg"; 
else
    gconftool -t string -s /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename "/root/Desktop/wall/q.jpg
fi
```

OR

```
#!/bin/bash

#  ws=$(wmctrl -d | wc -l)
cws=$(wmctrl -d | awk '/\*/ {print $1}')
if [ $cws = 0 ]; then
    wmctrl -s $cws
    gconftool -t string -s /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename "/root/Desktop/wall/b.jpg"
else
    gconftool -t string -s /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename "/root/Desktop/wall/q.jpg"
fi
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question please? It's hard to tell what you're asking or what your problem is.

Comment: ok..I want to use different wallpaper on other workspaces....but does not change background wallpapers..gconftool-2 -s /apps/compiz/plugins/wallpaper/screen0/options/bg_image -t string "[/root/Desktop/wall/q.jpg,/root/Desktop/wall/b.jpg] "  --->ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Seems very similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/4497/workspace-specific-wallpapers-with-compiz

Comment: Thank You.. But is not the right answer.

Comment: @erkanşentürk: there is an edit button below your post, which you can use to revise your question.  If you want to add more than a simple comment, it would be easier for everyone else to read if you used that button to add the new information.

Comment: @erkanşentürk - please confirm in your answer that you have added the fusions package as per your previous question (you should link to that in your question).  Also add the output of `ls -l /root/Desktop/wall/`

Comment: @erkanşentürk Please update your question with this information instead of putting it in a reply in the comments

Comment: Yes Marco I  Updated

Comment: @erkanşentürk - your script file is very badly formatted.  Please can you correct.  Also how do you use this script file?

Comment: Yes I edited and Updated.

Comment: @erkanşentürk - I dont understand your code - wmctrl -d doesnt return the workspace number... at least not using the syntax you are using.  The code itself looks like it needs to run once on each workspace.  It does not run if you click on each workspace manually.

Comment: Thank You Very Much @fossfreedom..How to Always will be change as Automatic background wallpapers.... with is init.d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the Wallpaper plugin for Compiz by installing compiz-fusion-plugins-extra (`sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra`). It will show up under the Utility category in CompizConfig Settings Manager.
[image]

Before you can use it, you'll have to configure Nautilus to not draw the desktop. Run `gconf-editor` and uncheck the setting **/apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop**. This will make all of your desktop icons disappear, and there is no solution to this drawback at this time.

To configure the Wallpaper plugin, add images to the list of backgrounds. They will be assigned to workspaces in the order they are listed.

CompizConfig

Comment: > >Thank YOU +                                                                 -   But  is not the right answer.Because I am needed wmctrl control scipt ....for left -right at click on workspaces.