# How can I prevent programs from switching workspaces?

Tags: unity, launcher, workspaces

I want to prevent programs from switching workspaces. If I'm working in one workspace and a program in another workspace has a dialog box come up, it interrupts whatever I'm doing. Similarly, if I switch to a workspace, click to open a program, then switch back to the first workspace, the program will open in the workspace I'm currently on, rather than the workspace I opened it in.

Basically, I want a program to be locked to a workspace and unable to switch.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/75663/application-does-not-open-in-the-same-workspace-when-switched-during-loading?rq=1

Comment: Do you want to permanently lock specific applications to specific workspaces (e.g. Firefox and Terminal always on workspace 1, GIMP always on workspace 2, and so on)? Or would the specific workspace potentially change each time you open the application?

Comment: Doesn't it work to right click on the application window bar and re-select the "only on this workspace" option? I've just tried on my computer and it worked perfectly...

Answer (score 2):

To fix an application to a specific viewport (you can *manually* move it after it has opened), use Compiz.

1. Install CompizConfig Settings Manager using Ubuntu Software Manager. Warning: you can mess up your interface if you fiddle with bits you don't know, so follow the instructions here carefully.
2. Open *CompizConfig Settings Manager* (also known as CCSM).
3. Choose *Window Management* from the left-hand menu.
4. Choose *Place Windows* from the right-hand side.
   [image: CCSM Place Windows]
5. Select the tab *Fixed Window Placement*.

Now, for each application whose window you want to place in a fixed viewport:

1. Open the application.
2. In CCSM, under *Windows with fixed viewport*, select *New*.
3. Press the big green + and then Grab. The cursor changes to a cross; click on the application window you want to fix (e.g. Firefox). The *Value* will be automatically filled in.
4. Press *Add*.
   [image: Getting to the Grab button]
5. Fill the *X Viewport Positions* (should be singular); this refers to the workspace number counting from the left.
6. Fill the *Y Viewport Positions* (should be singular); this refers to the workspace number counting from the top.
   In my example, I have chosen Firefox to always start in the third column, second row of the available workspaces.
   [image: Firefox example]
7. Press *Close*.

Thereafter, that application will always open in that specific viewport.

Answer (score -2):

Right-click on the workspaces bar
Click 'preferences'
Locate "Number of workspaces" under the heading "workspaces"
Click the minus sign until the number of workspaces is 1.
Close the window

Comment: He wants to prevent windows from switching workspaces, not disable the workspaces as whole.

Comment: He didn't specify that, and unlike the solution above, this one works in the general case!

Comment: "I want a program to be locked to a workspace and unable to switch." for me, he wants his workspaces working, not disabled.

Comment: @Braiam Having one workspace does exactly that. He could always increase the number of workspaces again if he decides he likes them after all.